# Non-english url path

Tags: node.js, next.js

In next.js that uses php-like approach - files in pages folder became url paths. Like /pages/reader.js will be loaded by url http://localhost/reader.

Problem is that i can't undersand how to use non-english url path in next.js?

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-poincare-moege?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). (Update page to load from server)

Url example:

```
http://localhost/читатель
```

That changes internally by chrome to:

```
http://localhost/%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C
```

In next.js pages folder file named:

```
pages/читатель.tsx // not working
pages/%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C.tsx //working but i can't name files like that, i will not find what i need later.
```

Maybe php users resolved this somehow ;)

Comment: Have you tried naming the file exactly as in the url? In Cyrillic?

Comment: @emix yes, it's in example and not working :(

Comment: I think you miss the concept of url encoding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski can you explain? I don't think i miss it.

Comment: @emix added codesandbox example

Comment: One problem will be the encoding your file system uses to store that file name. That’s not necessarily UTF-8, and the web server probably doesn’t translate the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `encodeURI()` of core javascript which can convert the specific characters to the required url form

```
const url=encodeURI('читатель.tsx');
console.log(url);//%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C.tsx
```

Then we can use this path to navigate

Comment: When you want to navigate to that file you pass the file name in the url.. Right!!!! Now you can pass the encoded url that I've suggested

Comment: uri get encoded by browser, you don't need to encode it. Just forget it, you need to understand how next.js working first.

Comment: Got it ..You have to make custom path and redirect to that file